# Setting the interaction model of a Dygraph in Shiny for R

Tags: r, shiny, dygraphs, user-interaction

I am looking to add the custom interaction seen at http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/interaction under "Custom interaction model" into my Shiny web app.

As far as I understand it, this requires attaching some JS to the page and  setting the interaction model on the graph:

`interactionModel : {
    'mousedown' : downV3,
    'mousemove' : moveV3,
    'mouseup' : upV3,
    'click' : clickV3,
    'dblclick' : dblClickV3,
    'mousewheel' : scrollV3 
}`

However, `interactionModel` does not seem to be listed as a parameter in the `dyOptions` function on the R side.

**Is there a way to work around this?**

Update:

Looking at the source for `dyOptions`, it seems that options can be modified directly:

```
g <- dyGraph(series)

g$x$attr$option <- "Value"
```

However, setting the `interactionModel` here does not seem to work.

See: https://github.com/rstudio/dygraphs/blob/master/R/options.R

Update:

You can indeed set the options using:

```
g$x$attrs$option <- "Value" # Note that it is "attrs", not "attr"
```

This can be used to switch off the interaction mode:

```
graph$x$attrs$interactionModel <- "{}"
```

The remaining problem is passing JS function references via JSON to the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the JS function to pass JavaScript over JSON to the client.

In ui.R:

```
tags$head(tags$script(src="interaction.js"))
```

In server.R:

```
g <- dygraph(series(), main = "Graph", xlab = "Date", ylab = "Amount") %>%
    dySeries(label = "X")

g$x$attrs$interactionModel <- list(
    mousedown = JS("downV3"),
    mousemove = JS("moveV3"),
    mouseup = JS("upV3"),
    click = JS("clickV3"),
    dblclick = JS("dblClickV3"),
    mousewheel = JS("scrollV3"))
```