# Change interaction model of dygraph in shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

change of dygraph interaction model does not work in shiny/R.

I tried to use js to change interaction model as described in this contribution
If I use the code presented in the related contribution (link above), the dygraph is not rendered in shiny.
(Setting the interaction model to empty works as described)

As I recognized, the htmlwidget package is needed for the JS function. But where does the interaction.js used in ui.R come from?

Comment: As I am not familiar with posting here, I made heavy mistakes.

Comment: [link]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29098290/setting-the-interaction-model-of-a-dygraph-in-shiny-for-r